# Issue happened when union\minus on Oracle clob

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I have a table named "preference" which includes more than 100 columns in oracle,I wrote a little bit complicated SQL which need use keyword UNION/INTERSECT/MINUS to do a query.
Take a simple example:

```
 select a.* from preference a where a.id = ? union
 select a.* from preference a where a.id = ?
```

The business care have been changed due to unlimited length string storage on demand. one column need to be re-defined to Clob type. Oracle don't allow union on the clob type, so ideally the a.* cannot be used here.

I changed SQL to like below:

```
 select a.a,a.b,a.c... from preference a where a.id = ? union
 select a.a,a.b,a.c... from preference a where a.id = ?
```

It lists all columns except clob and then I have to do another selection to append the Clob value together. Is that a good idea?

The Another issue brought from above case is that: as I mentioned this table has large columns, list all columns in sql it make SQL much longer. Is there expression I can select all columns but getting rid of specific one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle when delaing with log does not allow union/minus but allows union all, may be you can rewrite your query using union all and use a select *. in the select clause you can issue a select a.* or list every column.

After reading your question my main concern is memory usage on Java, are you using an orm to load the data? or are you using the jdbc api?

If you are loading all the clobs into some strings you could end with an OutOfMemoryError. My advice is to load the clob only for rows you need to show to the user (or for the rows where the clob filed has to be processed).

Can you give more insight about your application (the numer fo rows it has to process) and your data (epsecially the clob size)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am using JDBC to talk to oracle, the clob is not so big(general less than 10000 byte), for system performance concern we are loading the Frequently used data into memory. the example is not a real case so I must use UNION/INTERSECT/MINUS in this SQL condition.

Comment: I am concerning now the SQL is very long, because it is listing every column, will this affect oracle execution performance? Is any SQL language I can select all columns expect explicate one